# return prepared statement error in json array

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I am trying to understand if there is a way to return a prepared statement mysqli error in json. Below is my code. The code returns the form_pass in the array even though the sql doesnt actually work.

```
if($pass){
$stmt2 = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
$sql = 'UPDATE `users` SET `fname` = ?,`lname` = ?,`email` = ?,`username` = ?,`password` = ?,`active` = ?,`enc` = ? WHERE `id` = ?';
if(mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt2,$sql)){
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2,'sssssiii',$fname,$lname,$email,$username,$password,$active,$ran,$id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
    if(mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt2) == 0){
        $return_arr['error_msg'] = mysqli_stmt_error($stmt2);
    } else {
        $return_arr['form_pass'] = 'true';
    }
}
}
print json_encode($return_arr);
```

I've tried using something like

```
if(!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2)){
 $return_arr['error_msg'] = mysqli_stmt_error($stmt2);
}
```

and

```
if(mysqli_stmt_error($stmt2)){
 $return_arr['error_msg'] = mysqli_stmt_error($stmt2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the SQL fails, `mysqli_stmt_affected_rows` will return `-1`, not `0`. Try using this if statement instead.

```
if(mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt2) <= 0){
```